# Start WPF app from unit test in its own AppDomain

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization, nunit, appdomain

I am trying to run a WPF App from nunit. Since I only can run one App per AppDomain I instantiate a new AppDomain per acceptance test. When I do that, I run into serialization exceptions.

```
namespace Tests
{
    [TestFixture, RequiresSTA, Serializable]
    public class ApplicationTests
    {
        private MainWindow mainWindow;
        private bool guiVisible;
        private App app;

        [TestCase("app domain name for instance of App")]
        [TestCase("app domain name for another instance of App")]
        public void ApplicationTest(string name)
        {
            AppDomain appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(name);
            //appDomain.ExecuteAssembly(@"C:\Users\bp\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\bin\Debug\WpfApplication1.exe");

            CrossAppDomainDelegate action = () =>
            {
                app = new App();
                app.InitializeComponent();
                app.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded, new Action(() => AppOnActivated(null, null)));
                app.Run();
            };
            appDomain.DoCallBack(action);
        }

        private void AppOnActivated(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            if (!guiVisible)
            {
                mainWindow = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
                mainWindow.ButtonViewModel = new ButtonViewModel();
                mainWindow.ButtonViewModel.Name = "bla";

                guiVisible = true;
            }

            app.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

The exception I receive now:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException : Type is not
>   resolved for member 'Tests.ApplicationTests,Tests, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

I made the test class `[Serializable]` which does not help either.

Help is very much appreciated. I *just* want to start my WPF application from an `NUnit` test so that I can write acceptance tests for my application. I keep running into different walls and eventually whatever path I choose seems to lead to a dead end...

Many thanks in advance,

Bas

Comment: @EliArbel I updated the question with the complete test file. Am I not very familiar with `AppDomain`s, what do you suggest I'd do wrt assembly base paths? And maybe more important, what I am trying to do **is** possible, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AppDomains are software-isolated processes in .NET. This means you can't just reference objects belonging to one AppDomain from another. Objects can be either copied by value (serialization) or by reference using `MarshalByRefObject`. Since WPF's objects are neither of those, you can't move them around AppDomains.

For your your testing purposes, you could use a simpler approach: run everything within the new AppDomain, and use the `SetData` and `GetData` methods to transfer data to assert on.

```
[TestCase("app domain name for instance of App")]
[TestCase("app domain name for another instance of App")]
public void ApplicationTest(string name)
{
    AppDomain appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(name, 
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence,
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation);
    appDomain.DoCallBack(StartApp);
    Assert.IsTrue((bool)appDomain.GetData("GuiVisible"));
    AppDomain.Unload(appDomain);
}

// using a static method instead of a lambda makes sure
// you haven't captured anything
private static void StartApp()
{
    app = new App();
    app.InitializeComponent();
    app.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded,
       new Action(() => AppOnActivated()));
    app.Run();
}

private static void AppOnActivated()
{
    var mainWindow = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
    mainWindow.ButtonViewModel = new ButtonViewModel();
    mainWindow.ButtonViewModel.Name = "bla";

    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetValue("GuiVisible") = true;

    app.Shutdown();
}
```

Comment: Hi once more Eli, tried your approach, unfortunately it runs me into wall number 4: `An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Tests.dll but was not handled in user code.` when `appDomain.DoCallBack(StartApp);` is executed. (I entered a breakpoint in StartApp, which does not hit). I really am surprised how cumbersome a trivial thing like executing a WPF App from a unit test is... I hope this only makes you more determined to help, but I can imagine the opposite as well :). Thx in advance, and also a big thank you for the extra pieces of information

Comment: Hi Eli, I am specifically looking in this direction so that I can test the integration aspects of the App, instead of the `ViewModel`s in isolation. With your additional feedback I receive yet another exception: `System.IO.IOException : Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() returns null. Set the Application.ResourceAssembly property`. Adding `Application.ResourceAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(App));` does not resolve the problem. Do you have more tips? I am not ready to give up just yet :). Thanks for your help so far already!

Comment: OMG, and suddenly the damn button becomes green!! Oh Eli, I'd vote you president. I have the feeling I read the entire internet in the meantime, but... the end result, only thanks to you, is a green test! Thx!